# I am not sure what the issue is in this python program

Tags: python

I am trying to code a bubble sort algorithm. It was working perfectly until I tried to add the second section, which essentially changes the input("c") into a float, only if need be.

```
def bs(l):
    s=True
    while s:
        s=False
        for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
            if l[i]>l[i+1]:
                s=True
                h=l[i+1]
                l[i+1]=l[i]
                l[i]=h
    return l

b=[]
for q in range(int(input("How many numbers do you want to sort?"))):
    print("Enter the value for place number",q+1)
    c=input()
    c=list(c)
    if "." in c:
        c="".join(c)
        c=float(c)
        b.append(c)
    c=int(c)
    b.append(c)

print("\nThe numbers in order, are:\n\nSmallest",bs(b),"Largest\n")
```

Thank you, as any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this part:

```
if "." in c:
    c="".join(c)
    c=float(c)
    b.append(c)
c=int(c)
b.append(c)
```

to have else: branch

```
if "." in c:
    c="".join(c)
    c=float(c)
    b.append(c)
else:
    c=int(c)
    b.append(c)
```